# SQL query with SUM and DATE_FORMAT

Tags: mysql

I hope for your help

I have three tables with relation, activity [id, amount, completed], brand_to_activity [id, activity_id, brand_id], brand [id, name] Need to get the top 3 brands selling by the sum grouped by month, for example, in January, the amount is 100 [this is the sum of the three best selling brands in January], the completed column in unixtime therefore you have to use DATE_FORMAT, i have now the following:

```
SELECT `activity`.*, SUM(activity.amount) as groupAmount,
        DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(activity.completed), '%m-%Y') as grouping
FROM `activity` 
LEFT JOIN `brand_to_activity` ON `activity`.`id` = `brand_to_activity`.`activity_id` 
WHERE (`activity`.`completed` BETWEEN '1546300800' AND '1577750400') 
GROUP BY `grouping` ORDER BY `activity`.`completed`
```

Must be something like this:

```
Grouping | Amount | Profit | Note 
January    100      50       Philips, Sony, Apple 
February   100      50       Apple, Microsoft, Canon
March      50       50       Philips, Apple, AOC
```

version MariaDB 10

```
https://mega.nz/#!zFdAHACA!2CCVBVjMvwAxMqEz202a107s1CDxKc8jkvZiGQ5NJ0c
https://mega.nz/#!jNFCCQiL!MODxZR5kwCBXG6789uBZEVZhsdcZxY8W55qyIa-B4KQ
https://mega.nz/#!XRcAWAIT!xASyVxE3ucRiVtLJmjCKys7plImxLMOH99dRQVVSkDM
```

Comment: Please provide sample data along with the expected output.Also specify your MySQL version

Comment: Grouping | Amount | Profit  | Note

January      100         50        Philips, Sony, Apple
February    100          50       Apple, Microsoft, Canon
March          50          50       Philips, Apple, AOC



MariaDB 10

Comment: Please do not post it as an image. Also provide the sample data for your expected output @John. With that only we will able to replicate your scenario.